# Change Color of Link

Tags: css

I have a link inside a DIV. How can I change the color of this link inside this div. This code does not seem to work

```
<style type="text/css">
.someDiv
{

    font-size:14px;            
    color:#c62e16;
}
</style>

<div id="someDiv">
<a href="http://www.some.com" id="someLink">SOne Text</a> 
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
.someDiv a {

   font-size:14px;
   color:#c62e16;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

ids are accessed by a pound sign (#), and classes are accessed by a period (.)

```
<style type="text/css">
#someDiv a
{
    font-size:14px;            
    color:#c62e16;
}
</style>

<div id="someDiv">
<a href="http://www.some.com" id="someLink">SOne Text</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work, as you need to hit the anchor tag specifically to change it's appearance. So the correct selector would be `#someDiv a`

Comment: @lols referencing a class wouldn't have fixed the problem for you, you still need to change it to a pound sign or use <div class="someDiv">

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong selector. You have an `id="someLink"`, and the CSS is looking for the `class="someLink"`. Try with `#someLink`, it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#someDiv a{
 color: #hexcode;
}
```

That will work too, you use the selector to select ALL the elements of the type "a" in a div with the id="someDiv".

Answer (score 0):

While you're using the wrong selector for `someDiv` you will usually need to set `a` colours separately:

```
 #someDiv, #someDiv a {
     color: red;
 }
```